# How to read a specified line in a txt file (batch)

Tags: batch-file

I found this line of code on this site that echos a text file line by line:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (filename.txt) DO echo %%i
```

I am trying to echo a specific line in the text file. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Which specific line? Line 763? Or a line containing a specific word?

Comment: I will set a variable that would be used to specify the line I want.

For example: If I set a variable "line" to 100, then when %line% is used in the code, would echo the 100th line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will echo line 100.

```
@echo off
set "var=100"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "filename.txt" ^|findstr "^%var%:"') do echo %%b
```

Lines starting with `:` will not be complete.

Answer (score 3):

This method get the desired result in a faster way, especially if the file is large.

```
@echo off
set "line=100"

(for /L %%i in (1,1,%line%) do set /P "result=") < filename.txt
echo %result%
```